# Add row to DataGridView using Designer

Tags: c#, visual-studio

Is there a way to add rows to a dataGridView while in the visual designer? I have added this code, and the visual designer recognizes and displays the rows, but whenever I make a change, my code gets deleted. If I put this code in the non-designer portion of the partial class definition, then the designer doesn't visually show I have added these rows but at least it doesn't delete it when I make changes with the visual designer.

It makes sense that the designer should delete and modify its code as necessary, but what is the right way to add a row so that it meets both requirements?

1. Shows up in visual designer
2. Isn't deleted upon changes in visual designer

Either an answer explaining where to put the code or where to click in the designer is appreciated. If you can explain both, even better! Thanks!

```
this.dataGridView1.Rows.Add(9);
this.dataGridView1.Rows[0].HeaderCell.Value = "L1";
this.dataGridView1.Rows[1].HeaderCell.Value = "L2";
```

Here's an example of entering the code manually in the X.Designer.cs file

```
private void InitializeComponent()
        {
             // Other code here - from designer
             this.dataGridView1.Rows.Add(9);
        }
```

[image]

After doing anything with the visual designer tools, e.g. adding another column in the visual designer, the programatically entered code in the X.Designer.cs file is deleted. The rows are all gone.

[image]

Comment: is it important to visualize them in the [designer] ? what's wrong with dealing with them programatically

Comment: Absolutely. The design is static, and I would much rather see it than compile and run the program every time I want feedback on my edits.

Comment: anyway it's not clear *what* is being deleted when *something* is being changed. Give us  an example that we can try and see this behavior. Though throughout all my experience I always manage my rows/cols programatically